# Trying to set the text of a QLabel as the __repr__ of a class's object and getting an error

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm trying to make the text in a QLabel change according to what the user selects in a combobox, the text I want to set being the `__repr__` function of the class. Here's the code I'm using to try to do what I want to:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Resonant Orbit Calculator")
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 400))

        m_label = QLabel()
        m_label.setText(object)

        c_box = QComboBox()
        c_box.addItems(planet.name for planet in planets_objects)
        c_box.addItems(moon.name for moon in moons_objects)

        c_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(m_label)
        layout.addWidget(c_box)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def text_changed(self, t):
        for element in planets_objects + moons_objects:
            if element.name == t:
                object = element
                break
        print(object)

        return object
```

And the error I'm getting is `TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'type'`. I kind of get that I'm using the wrong kind of information to set the QLabel as, but I can't figure out how else to do it.

Comment: Remove all the lines that refer to `object`, and also replace all `m_label` with `self.m_label`. Then you can do `if element.name == t: self.m_label.setText(repr(element))`.

Comment: why do you use `object` in `setText()`? First: You use this variable before you assign any value to this variable. Second: `object` is special class in Python and you shouldn't use it as variable. Third: to change text you have to use `setText()` because changing value only in variable `object` you can't change text in `Label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes.

1. `object` is special object/class in Python and you shouldn't use it as variable.
2. you use `setText(object)` in `__init__` but you never assign text to variable `object`
3. you should use `self.` in `self.m_label` to have access to this widget in other functions.
4. in other functions you have to use `setText(..)` to change text in label. You can't change it by assigning new text to variable `object`

If you need result from `__repr__` then use `repr(...)`

---

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Resonant Orbit Calculator")
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 400))

        self.m_label = QLabel()
        self.m_label.setText('Default text on start')

        c_box = QComboBox()
        c_box.addItems(planet.name for planet in planets_objects)
        c_box.addItems(moon.name for moon in moons_objects)

        c_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(m_label)
        layout.addWidget(c_box)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def text_changed(self, selected):
        for element in planets_objects + moons_objects:
            if element.name == selected:
                #self.m_label.setText(element)
                self.m_label.setText(repr(element))
                break
                # OR
                #return
```

BTW: `text_changed` is executed by `PyQt` but it doesn't know what to do with returned value - so using `return object` is useless.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Now it works wonderfully. If it isn't too much of a bother, could I ask you something else? I'm still a newbie (clearly) and could use a little more clarification. On your number 3, what you're saying is that putting prefacing the variable with `self.` allows it to be accessed by functions outside of the init function? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: if you create `m_label` without `self.` (in `__init__`) then you create `local variable` which exists only inside `__init__` and you can't access it `text_changed`. If in `text_changed` you would create other variable without `self.` then it would be also `local variable` which exists only inside `text_changed` and you couldn't access it in `__init__` or in other functions in `MainWindow`.